# html css dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, dropdown

This is my first ever post to Stack Overflow and I'm not familiar with forum regulations with posting. So please let me know anything that I have done wrong. I have researched this issue in the forums and nothing I've come across gives me a clear answer.

I am trying to create a dropdown menu from the "News" element, but I never get any visible result when running the code. I tried to change the `.dropdown-content`'s `display` value to `block` to see if it would make the list visible, but nothing showed. What am I missing?

```css
body{
 background-image: url("images/seamless-panda-bear-pattern.jpg");
 font-size: 100%;
 width: 80%;
 margin: auto;
 font-family: Palatino,"Palatino", Arial;

}

#top{
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 padding-left: 10px;
 border: 2px solid white;
 font-family: Copperplate,"Copperplate Gothic Light",fantasy;
 opacity: 0.85;
 padding-left: 25px;
}

#menu{
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #333;
 position: fixed;
 width: 80%;
}
li{
 float: left;
}

#login{
 float: right;
 padding-right: 20px;
}

li a{
 display: block;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;

}
li a:hover{
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
}

li.dropdown{
 display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content{
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
 min-width: 160px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0,2);
 padding: 12px 16px;
 z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a{
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 12px 16px;
 color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
 display: block;
}


#bio{

}

#bottom{

}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<ul style="list-style-type: none" id="menu">
 <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
 <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropbtn" href="#">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
   <a href="#">Games</a>
   <a href="#">Web Design</a>
   <a href="#">Travel</a>
  </div>
 </li>
 <!-- create a link to a part of the same page for contact info -->
 <li><a href="#bottom">Contact info</a></li>
 <li id="login"><a href="login.html">Log In</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: When I run the code snippet it works just as you want it to, is there something I'm missing?  P.S. your post is GREAT!

Comment: You actually did what most people dont and provided enough code.  YAY!!!  It works on my browser, CHROME by the way as well.

Comment: Seems to be working in Safari

Comment: What browser are you using??? (that you code isn't working on)  It looks like `display: block;` has full browser coverage as you can see here: http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20block%3B

Comment: I have updated the css code to show everything I have (I know I shouldn't normally do this, but seeing as I can't pinpoint the issue...). I have tried on Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Comment: you could pinpoint which css property is giving you issues based on the responses here. It seems your code was working before you added additional CSS to your post. The drop down no longer works for me, so that means whatever additional CSS you added is the culprit. Remove the additional CSS and add it back one CSS rule at a time to see which one contains the CSS that is giving you issues.

Comment: Ahh! I removed the 'position:fixed;' part of my '#menu' selector and it now works as intended! Is there a way to have both work together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve your position fixed issue.  You can add `position: fixed;` to `#nav` and change the width on `#menu` from `width: 80%;` to `width: 100%;`

Here's a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbff15ps/3/).

Hope that helped!

Comment: Only issue I find is the Log In element no longer floats to the right of the screen. It sits next to Contact Info. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It was due to the `padding` for `#login`, if you change it from `padding-right: 20px;` to `padding-left: 20px;` that should fix your issue!  See updated JS Fiddle!

Comment: Actually, just remove that `padding` altogether! (See updated JS Fiddle)

Comment: Hmm, what I meant was I wanted the navigation bar's width to match the 'body' selector's width and have the 'Log In' element to sit at the right end. I'm noticing with increased padding-left, I could get the results I want. However, wouldn't a percentage of the screen fit better for the webpage to look equal to all screen resolutions?

Comment: I got the results I wanted by adding 'width: 80%' to the #nav selector. Thank you!

Comment: Whether this is better or not is quite subjective, but I had fun playing with the CSS a bit and got this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xxmx7e0c/)

Comment: @NickPrieto I'm glad you got it figured out!

Comment: @JacqueGoupil Was that link directed at me? If it was, it's a great JS Fiddle, can I use it in my post?

Comment: @JeffArries Sure, no problem. I pretty much just moved a few styles around.